# What is this small pink-flowered shrub?

Tags: identification, shrubs

This was planted a few years ago by a landscaper that I am no longer in contact with. Two of the four that were planted have died and I'd like to know what they are so I can go get some more.

[image: http://imgur.com/3xZvs7w]

Answer (score 6):

This is a [weigela](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weigela)  which flowers in late spring to early summer with trumpet shaped flowers. They are native to temperate East Asia, specifically Japan, Korea, and Northern China. In the late 1980's, a series of dwarf Weigelas developed by Felicitas Svejda of Agriculture Canada became available.  They are all named after dance steps like Tango or Minuet.  I suspect you have the [Tango](http://www.missouribotanicalgarden.org/gardens-gardening/your-garden/plant-finder/plant-details/kc/w750/weigela-florida-tango.aspx) cultivars which should get no more than 3 feet (1 M) tall and be reliably hardy to USDA zone 4. They need full sun and tolerate most soil types.

Your plants are doing much better than mine. Mine get a lot of dead wood and look poorly in the spring until they leaf out. They should not be placed where heavy snow is likely to accumulate.

Comment: Cool.  It's good to have someone here that knows something about these.  Thanks for the info. I learned something today.